# AjaxControlToolkit:ModalPopupExtender not working at second attempt

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have created a user control which contains an `ImageButton`.

Upon clicking this `ImageButton` I open an `AjaxControlToolkit:ModalPopupExtender`.

When I run this VB.NET application and click on the `ImageButton` the `.modalBackground` CSS is loaded, but when I close the `ModalPopupExtender` and again click on the `ImageButton`, on the second load the `.modalBackground` CSS is not working.

```
.modalBackground
{   
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: gray;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);      
    opacity: 0.7;     
}
```

Comment: please provide the markup code, it's possible that you're missing a property

Answer (score 0):

I had that kind of problem, it was caused by storing a reference to the popup control in a session. The solution was to recursively find the popup control by looking in all parent controls:

```
private T FindParentControl<T>( T control )
    where T : class
{
    if( control.Parent is T )
    {
        return control.Parent as T;
    }
    return control.Parent != null ? FindParentControl( control.Parent ) : null;
}
```